# meaning of this ps aux output

Tags: command-line

I was not sure if I am running `named`. So I did the following:

```
$ ps aux | grep named  
root      6613  0.0  0.0  13588   920 pts/2    S+ 23:12   0:00 grep --color=auto named
```

what this output exactly means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that no `named` process was running. The reason why `grep` shows up is because it was executing while `ps` was started. To add headers, and avoid adding `grep` to the output, use:

```
$ ps u -C named
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
```

As you can see, I do not have `named` running. You can add the `h` option to hide this header as in:

```
$ ps uh -C named
```